# Game Object Thread?

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a game. It's a simple whack-a-mole type of game where something pops-up the screen and you click on it to kill it. I was thinking of giving the "moles" their own thread so that they can do their own animation, event handling, etc. in their own lifecycle until eventually killing themselves.

Will this kind of "each object has its own thread" implementation be good for an Android game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay single threaded until you actual need to change - especially for a simple game, you won't have the kinds of performance problems that need threading.

At any rate the general approach is not to thread out individual entities, but entire steps of algorithms performed across 100s or 1000s, or even entire systems (e.g. audio, physics etc.) - and perhaps the most extreme but common case is to split your rendering submission into its own thread for all rendering, with animation, physics, gameplay logic etc on another thread, in exchange for single frame latency on everything.

Not to mention that the overhead of having very many threads often becomes limiting - if you have 2 or 3 moles it might be fine, but if you have many more you will quickly reach the point of diminishing returns - not to mention the difficulties inherent in keeping many threads in sync and avoiding deadlocks, race conditions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not. Do not give each mole its own thread. This would be too much use of threads while it is needless to say that in this type of game you do not need such a number of threads. Just keep everything in the main thread and use some listeners to kill moles. (=make invisible)

Yes, it is a performance issue and a matter of developer's decision. Why should you create a thread for each mole? This is the right question because doing so is a far more unrealistic decision. Will each mole access a database? communicate with a server? I don't think so.

Anyway, since it is a mole on the screen, you will only need one instance of it that you can render/move it around/disable/etc in the main thread.

Comment: May I ask why you don't think a thread for each mole would be good? For now I'm assuming that it's a performance reason however, as Dhaivat Pandya pointed out in the other answer, thread pooling would be a good way to eliminate most of the overhead.

Comment: I edited the answer.. Listen, everytime i edit an answer i comment saying so... Do you get informed that some1 edited his answer?

Comment: _1 mole on the screen_ - it's going to be a lot of moles on the screen
this is one of the reasons I was thinking of giving them their own threads, so that not all the processing will be on the main loop. but then again, I've yet to test which one really is faster. I am keeping your feedback in mind though

Answer (score 1):

This could work, if there aren't a ton of objects, and a ton of activity for each object.

I would suggest [thread pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). Pull out inactive objects out of threads and put in active threads.